# Should I do cardio each day throughout the week on a PPL workout, or should I do it on separate days?

Tags: weight-loss, bodybuilding, cardio

Should I do cardio each day throughout the week on a PPL workout, or should I do it on separate/dedicated days without resistance training? Will one of these approaches affect my gains? I'm currently doing a body recomp, with a high body fat percentage.